# Does J2V8 uses android system V8 or compiles and provides own one?

Tags: javascript, android, v8, embedded-v8, j2v8

I'd like to use android system V8 to run JS and i'd like to avoid cross-compiling V8 and providing it as .so in my app to reduce apk size. Does [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8) use system one or compiles and provides own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles and embeds v8 in .so for both arm and x86. [aar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/eclipsesource/j2v8/j2v8/4.5.1-SNAPSHOT/) takes about 7.5 Mb (which is not suitable for me).